# Somar quantidade vendida de todos produtos em SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas em um Select através de um INNER JOIN, gostaria de saber o que fiz de errado para que seja exibida a lista de produtos de todas vendas e a soma total da quantidade vendida de cada produto..

```
$consulta2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT L.ID_PRODUTO,SUM(L.QUANTIDADE) QUANT FROM pedido_produto L INNER JOIN produtos E ON L.ID_PRODUTO = E.ID GROUP BY L.ID_PRODUTO ORDER BY QUANT ");
$consulta2->execute();
$rowCount = $consulta2->rowCount(); // numero de linhas
if($rowCount > 0){
while ($linha = $consulta2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$quant[]     = $linha['QUANT'];
```

Ficaria assim:

> ```
> Produto 1 - 10 Vendas
> Produto 2 - 33 Vendas
> ```

Já estou utilizando assim a consulta, gostaria de uma resposta que fosse dentro do select que tenho aqui e não outro tipo de meio para chegar ao mesmo fim.

Comment: Qual foi o resultado obtido?

Comment: O que foi retornado para você? De toda forma, você esqueceu de usar o comando ```AS``` para renomear a soma de quantidade com o alias  **QUANT**. Deveria ficar assim: ```"SELECT L.ID_PRODUTO, SUM(L.QUANTIDADE) AS QUANT FROM pedido_produto L INNER JOIN produtos E ON L.ID_PRODUTO = E.ID GROUP BY L.ID_PRODUTO ORDER BY QUANT DESC" ``` . Se você não colocar o parâmetro do ASC ou DESC no order by ele ordena de forma padrão ASC, mas é bom colocar para boa prática.

Comment: O que você quer retornar, se o problema é a quantidade de vendar, você deveria reavaliar seu `SUM(L.QUANTIDADE)`.

Answer (score 1):

O campo `l.id_produto` vai aparecer para todas as linhas do conjunto-resultado e, no final, quando o valor de `l.id_produto` for nulo, o valor de `quant` será o total geral.

```
SELECT l.id_produto, SUM(l.quantidade) quant
FROM pedido_produto l
JOIN produtos e ON e.id = l.id_produto
GROUP BY ROLLUP(l.id_produto)
ORDER BY quant;
```

Answer (score 0):

No meu entendimento, mudaria a ordem do "from" e do "inner join".

```
    SELECT * 
      P.ID,
      SUM(PO.QUANTIDADDE) as QUANT
    FROM PRODUTOS P
    INNER JOIN PEDIDO_PRODUTO PO ON PO.ID = P.ID_PRODUTO
    GROUP BY P.ID
    ORDER BY QUANT ASC
```